# RewriteRule Works With "Match Everything" Pattern But Not Directory Pattern

Tags: mod-rewrite, rewrite

I'm trying to redirect newsletter URLs from my local server to an Amazon S3 bucket.

So I want to redirect from:

`https://mysite.com/assets/img/newsletter/Jan12_Newsletter.html`

to:

`https://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucket/newsletters/legacy/Jan12_Newsletter.html`

Here's the first part of my rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Is it in the newsletters directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/assets/img/newsletter/)(.+) [NC]
# Is not a 2008-2011 newsletter
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.+)(11|10|09|08)_Newsletter.html$ [NC]
## -> RewriteRule to S3 Here <- ##
```

If I use this `RewriteRule` to point to the new subdirectory on S3 it will **NOT** redirect:

`RewriteRule ^(/assets/img/newsletter/)(.+) https://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucket/newsletters/legacy/$2 [R=301,L]`

However if I use a blanket expression to capture the entire file path it **WILL** redirect:

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucket/newsletters/legacy/$1 [R=301,L]`

Why does it only work with a "match everything" expression but not a more specific expression?

Comment: the `^(/assets/img/newsletter/)(.+)` regex does match the Request URI `/assets/img/newsletter/Jan12_Newsletter.html`. what does the rewrite log says? I usually put it on RewriteLogLevel 5.

Comment: @PetterH It seems to match when I test it in [Regexr](http://regexr.com/39bdn) and the [.htaccess tester](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/).

Comment: It is very strange since you rewritecond matces with that excact same regex so maybe there are some junk chars or something.  It would be interresting to see the rewritelog...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you capture the part of the URI you are interested in already in the first `RewriteCond` block, you don't have to capture it again to do the `RewriteRule`, and since both of your `RewriteCond`s are met, there's no need to parse the URI a third time, so a simple caret would do it.

```
# Is it in the newsletters directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/assets/img/newsletter/(.+) [NC]
# Is not a 2008-2011 newsletter
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(?:11|10|09|08)_Newsletter.html$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucket/newsletters/legacy/%1 [R=301,L]
```

Therefore this should do the trick (matches from `RewriteCond`s are prefixed with an `%` in stead of `$`).

It may not be explaining why your `RewriteRule` does not match because it looks OK to me, but using this method, it is unnceccesary.

Answer (score 1):

The RewriteRule has some not needed stuff, which could cause this behavior.

Try this instead:

```
RewriteRule ^/assets/img/newsletter/(.+)$ https://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucket/newsletters/legacy/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Here I use the "one-or-more" quantifier to regex, so that $1 cannot be empty at any point.

Comment: Good point about using `+` instead of `*`. Alas it still doesn't work.